# Show success message after redirect in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to show a success message after redirect, on the new page. When I insert my record in a table, my page will be redirected to another page, and on that page I want to show a success message.

I am using the following code:

```
if($insert){ 
    <script>
        var url='http://www.testing.com'; 
        window.location =url; 
    </script>
    <div id="usp-error-message">successfully register</div>
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming $insert is returning the correct value you can pass a value through the querystring to the other pages like this:

```
if($insert){ 
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.testing.com?success=yes' );
    exit;
}
```

and then on that page use the following code to display a message somewhere. Exactly where depends on that page:

```
if( "yes" == $_GET['success'] ){
    echo "<div id='usp-error-message'>successfully register</div>";
}
```

Comment: is this safe from Cross-site Scripting?